# [Video Call]Cannot recall the Video Chat

Tags: android, quickblox

I create a CallActivity implement Video Call webrtc. I use quickblox sdk version 2.2.2. The Video Call work fine. But when i ended a Video Call and finish() CallActivity, then i restart CallActivity again, the Video Call not work any more, i can start a new Video Call, but my partner can not receive this Call. I must force stop my app by app manager, Video Call work fine again. Maybe the video call session has problem!
How to recall when restart CallActivity. My destroy() method on CallActivity.

```
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    handler.removeCallbacks(sendVideoCall);
    if (QBChatService.isInitialized()) {
        try {
            if (QBRTCClient.isInitiated()) {
                endCall(getCurrentSession().getUserInfo());
                //QBRTCClient.getInstance().getSessions().clear();
                QBRTCClient.getInstance().removeCallback(this);
                QBRTCClient.getInstance().close();
            }


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    currentSession = null;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We recommend you to update your SDK version to the latest one (2.2.6) as it has most video call issues fixed.

You can download it and chtck the framework changelog here: http://quickblox.com/developers/Android#Download_Android_SDK